# BaQend - DBready at initializing, check login status of user

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, app-startup, baqend

I'm working with **BaQend** & **Ionic2** and try to get some task at App-start.

**1. DBready**

I don't want to do this at every single page:

```
ionViewCanEnter(): Promise<baqend> {
        // Check if the Baqend SDK is ready and wait for initialization
        return this.ready.resolve().then(db => this.db = db);
}
```

I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
          // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
          this.statusBar.styleDefault();
          this.splashScreen.hide();
          return this.ready.resolve().then(db => this.db = db);
        });
      }
```

**2. Check users login status**

On App start, i should check the login status of the user and if he/she isn't signed in, it should open the LoginModal.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    if (this.db.User.me) {
      console.log(this.db.User.me.username,' entered HomePage with ID ', this.db.User.me.id);
    } else {
      this.openLoginModal()
      console.log('Hello Anonymous');
    }
  }
```

This is a working code for the rootPage, but it would be better to get this into app startup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify where the initializeApp() comes from?

Comment: from "app/app.component.ts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good point,

we have updated our ionic starter. We moved the DBReady check to the root view. 
In our starter that is the tabs.component.ts. The Rootview then always waits on the db, before it renders the child views.

If you update the [db.service.ts](https://github.com/Baqend/ionic-starter/blob/master/src/app/db.service.ts) as well, you can also use the db exported from the SDK now.

```
import { db } from "baqend";
```

Comment: and how do i realise the login check?

Comment: The login check can be implemented in the root view too.

Comment: is there a way to implement this into the app.component.ts? i don't use tabs, i just use the sidemenu.